# Convert CPU library to CUDA

Tags: c++, cuda

I have a CPU library that I am using (ICA-Independent Component Analysis). I need to convert my project to CUDA, but I don't seem to find a library for CUDA. Is it possible to easily convert the library and use it in CUDA or do I have to rewrite the library by myself?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to modify that library.  It might be easy, it might not.  (I cannot tell, because I do not know what is in that library.)

NVIDIA offers an OpenACC compiler [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/openacc).

There are many libraries available that use CUDA to perform computation on the GPU:  https://developer.nvidia.com/gpu-accelerated-libraries

I suggest using [Thrust](https://developer.nvidia.com/thrust) since it comes bundled with the CUDA SDK.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to look into OpenACC. In case your code is sufficiently GPU friendly (storage order, high parallel task granularity) you should be able to convert quite quickly. If you already have OpenMP directives you can basically add OpenACC kernel directives there, test it, then profile your data movement and probably you will need to manually specify a GPU data region to avoid too many copy operations.